# problemas con función en router con element

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

Hola buena tengo un error en react que no se solucionar al seguir un tutorial me lanza este error.

```
Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    40 |       
    41 |           <Route path='/'  element={<Home user={user}/>}/>
  > 42 |           <Route path='/login' element={() => <Login setLogin={() => setLogin(true)} />}/>
       |                                        
    43 |           <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
    44 |         
    45 |       </BrowserRouter>
```

esta parte queda marcada en rojo :
element={() => <Login setLogin={() => setLogin(true)} />}/>

este es la app.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom" 
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  useEffect ( () => {
    ( 
     async () => {
         try {
             const response = await axios.get('user');

             const user = response.data;

             setUser(user);
         } catch (e) {
             setUser(null);
         }
         
     }

    )();

 }, [login]);

  return (
  
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>
      
        <Nav user={user} setLogin={() => setLogin(false)}/>

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/'  element={<Home user={user}/>}/>
          <Route path='/login' element={() => <Login setLogin={() => setLogin(true)} />}/>
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
        </Routes>  
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  
        );
}

        export default App;
```

Aquí esta la pagina del  componente login.tsx por si puede servir de ayuda para solucionar o ver el problema :

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { SyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = ({ setLogin }: { setLogin: Function }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await axios.post('login', {
            email,
            password
        });

        setRedirect(true);
        setLogin();
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
    return (
        <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={submit}>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

            <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" required
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

        </form>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial y no sé como solucionar, si alguien puede ayudarme pues lo agradecería de antemano creo que es un tontería pero como el tutorial utiliza react-router-dom v5 y yo la versión v6 creo que es por eso pero no estoy segura.

Comment: el router v6 es bastante diferente al v5, prueba a desinstalar el v6 dando npm uninstall react-router-dom y luego instala la version 5 asi npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0.

Comment: `element={() => <Login setLogin={() => setLogin(true)} />` Esta sintáxis no parece estar en la doc de rv6, sugiero buscar un ejemplo ahí.